# PHP making unique link

Tags: php, url, blogs

I am trying to make a blog type system where you click the heading of one of the blog entries and you will be redirected to the full article. I am using substr to display a portion of the articles. The problem is the a href tag isnt doing anything so the reader cannot read the full article. If anyone can help that would be great.

```
<?php   
$dbinfo = "SELECT title, date, body FROM content ORDER BY blog_id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($dbinfo);

while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo substr("<h1>$data[0]</h1><br> <b>$data[1]</b><br> $data[2]", 0, 97)." ... "." read more<br><br><hr>";
echo '<a href="index.php?id=' . $result['blog_id'] . '">' . $result['title'] . ' </a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question in your question.

Comment: How does this code "not work"? seems like it should work fine to me.

Comment: Asking a question is completely overrated ;)

Comment: What does "the a href tag isnt doing anything" mean?

Comment: It does not make the title part of the blog a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear You can't use  $result['blog_id']

you have to use $data[index]  and the index have to be 0 or 1 or 2 ...

```
<?php
$dbinfo = "select blog_id,title,date,body from content order by blog_id DESC"

$result = mysql_query($dbinfo) or die("cann't execute query");

$num = mysql_num_rows($result)
$i=0;

while($i < $num)
{
$blog_id = mysql_result($result,$i,'blog_id');
$title = mysql_result($result,$i,'title');
$date = mysql_result($result,$i,'date');
$body = mysql_result($result,$i,'body');

$i++

echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1><small> ('.$data.') </small>';
echo '<p>'.substr($body,0,100).'<p>';
echo '<a href"index.php?id='.$blog_id.'"> Read More </a>';
}
?>
```

but dear i don't prefer to do substr here i prefer to do some kind of text summarization algothims take a look here 
http://www.binpress.com/app/php-summarizer/87
http://www.tools4noobs.com/summarize/script/

and if you don't want to do summerization you can use explode and implode function to take an specific number of words and display them

Comment: thanks for the reply ahmad but the code does not seem to be working :(